# Let be $f(z)$ a polynomial, show that exist $f(z_0)=a$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f(z)$ a polynomial and $a\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that exist a complex number $z_0$ such that, $f(z_0)=a$.

My approach:

Let be $f(z)=a_n(z-z_n)(z-z_{n-1})...(z-z_1)$, where $z_n$, with $n=1,2,3..$ are the roots of the $f(z)$. Now, suppose exist $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0)=a$, then $$f(z_0)=a_n(z_0-z_1)(z_0-z_2)...(z_0-z_n)=a$$

but not how to continue, some hint pls!.

Comment: $f$ should be non-constant, otherwise it fails for almost all $a$.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of algebra on the polynomial $f(z)-a$. The exceptions to that theorem are also the exceptions to your problem, as @DanielFischer just pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z) - a$ is a polynomial. So it has a zero somewhere.